# ASP - Dynamically validate textboxes without postback? - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, textbox

I have 4 text boxes (txtAV, txtAVcomments, txtWin, txtWinComments) plus a submit button (btnSubmit) on a form.

What I want to achieve is if either txtAV or txtWin (or both) contain an integer value greater than zero, show the respective txtAVcomments or txtWinComments (they are hidden at page_load) and dynamically apply a required field validator to them.

I thought I could do this in the btnSubmit_click event but this leads me to a problem:

When I have done this in the past I have only worked with a single text box and used code like:

```
If Not sometextbox.text = "0" Then
        'unhide control and create required field validator
    Else
        ' call code to add record
    End If
```

Trouble is, doing it this way with 2 textboxes has confused me a bit. I'm not entirely sure how to test both txtAV and txtWin to see if either or both of them contain an integer greater than 0 then unhide their respective comments boxes, apply the validators and only call the code to add the record if everything is valid.

Using winforms I would do the validation on the lostfocus event of the textboxes then just add the record in the button click, however I am unsure of any other way I could do the validation and unhiding of controls outside of the button click event in ASP. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax, and set your controls' autoPostBack = True.

You can do it without ajax, but it will be much neater on the eyes making use of ajax.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I wasn't aware that you could set a textbox to cause a post back. I was already using an update panel so I enabled autoPostBack on the textboxes and did the validation in the textChanged event. Working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers.